# Run Time Error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set when using Pie Chart in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

My Code:

```
Sub PieSourceData()
    Sheets("ReportSummary").ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
    Sheets("DataSheet").Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A245:B249")
End Sub
```

It is failing at the line :

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A245:B249")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is this line

```
 Sheets("DataSheet").Select
```

If you select that sheet then how is the chart active then ;)

And hence I always suggest to avoid the use of `.Select`. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179).

Try this

```
Sub PieSourceData()
    Sheets("ReportSummary").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("DataSheet").Range("A245:B249")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. It Worked !